# How to install portmaster on FreeBSD 8.4

Tags: freebsd

I updated my ports on VPS with clean FreeBSD 8.4 using

```
[cmd=#]portsnap fetch[/cmd]
[cmd=#]portsnap extract[/cmd]
```

But no /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster dir was created,

```
root@somehost:/usr/ports # ls -a
.               README          biology         finance         korean
..              Templates       cad             french          lang
CHANGES         Tools           chinese         ftp             mail
COPYRIGHT       UIDs            comms           games           math
GIDs            UPDATING        converters      german          misc
KNOBS           accessibility   databases       graphics        multimedia
Keywords        arabic          deskutils       hebrew          net-im
LEGAL           archivers       devel           hungarian
MOVED           astro           dns             irc
Makefile        audio           editors         japanese
Mk              benchmarks      emulators       java
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you got only a partial ports tree.  You are missing several directories from net-mgmt/ through x11-wm/ (27 categories).  You should try fetching and extracting the ports tree again.

Comment: yes, thanks, I earlier did like that, rebuilt ports and all was ok.